# PHP-LDAP & Windows Authentication

Tags: php, windows, authentication, ldap

**TLDR:** *What steps would you go through to setup PHP's LDAP authentication on a big, internal intranet with Windows users? Just need a checklist, please.*

I'm thinking my way around a project where an intranet will be hosted on a network with 500-1,000 Windows users. I'd like to use PHP's LDAP functions so that I can get AD/Windows user information without relying on people to enter it (I'd failsafe against failures and offer information entry as an alternative or error handler) and I understand the functionality, but am wondering ahead of time where exactly the LDAP has to be setup? Is it just compiled into PHP on the server that's hosted within the same network/domain controller? I don't need specifics or steps, just a generalized flow of what needs to be setup on which machine (like IIS, etc..).

This will be on a hand-compiled stack of Windows with the newest Apache, PHP, MySQL, etc. (all of which are actively up and functioning on localhost).

Sorry if I'm vague, I don't really know how else to word it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

compiling PHP with the `--with-ldap`-flag (and optionally `--with-ldap-sasl`) is sufficient to use ldap within PHP. With that set up you can access the AD-Server to do LDAP-based login and to access group-membership and whatever is needed.

You might find more information at php.net/manual/ldap.installation.php

So you have the Webserver with PHP, the DB can be either on the webserver or on a different machine and you've got the AD which should definitely be on a separate machine.

Comment: Concise and all I needed. Thanks!