# How to connect to SQL Server using Windows authentication on Linux/Apache using PHP?

Tags: php, sql-server, linux, apache, windows-authentication

How can I connect to a SQL Server using Windows authentication and the native SQL driver, when the PHP code is executed on a Linux machine under Apache or PHP-FPM ?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/how-to-connect-using-windows-authentication?view=sql-server-2017

> The credentials under which the Web server's process (or thread) is
> running must map to a valid SQL Server login in order to establish a
> connection.

So basically the question is how to do this with Linux/Apache/PHP-FPM ?

Comment: As far as I know you need to compile PHP with LDAP. http://php.net/manual/en/book.ldap.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using windows authentication with php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501729/using-windows-authentication-with-php)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35077694/php-ldap-windows-authentication

Comment: This is not quite what I'm asking about - I wan't to connect to a SQL Server, that requires Windows authentication, not to authenticate users against an active directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is to use kerberos and a keytab file to store the Windows user credentials and use something like [k5start](https://linux.die.net/man/1/k5start) to acquire and renew the kerberos ticket automatically.

This link [Connection problem Linux Apache+PHP to MS SQL Server using WindowsAuth / Kerberos ("No Kerberos credentials available")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55207519/connection-problem-linux-apachephp-to-ms-sql-server-using-windowsauth-kerbero) answers the PHP/Apache related part of this question.